# Checking if polylines are connecting using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, point, merge

The below picture shows the table of a shapefile, including fields of TotalCT, and coordinates of the ends of the line. I want to merge the lines if they are adjacent and only keep the field of TotalCT.

I have no idea about the logical flow of this arcpy code.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) tool (no need for ArcPy) which:

> Aggregates features based on specified attributes.

In your case just use a single attribute (`TotalCT`).

It looks like this will result in a multipart feature so, if you need to get the parts that do not touch as separate features, try running [Multipart to Singlepart](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/multipart-to-singlepart.htm) as a second step:

> Creates a feature class containing singlepart features generated by
>   separating multipart input features.

Alternatively, a one step process that could do this is described in a comment by @MichaelMiles-Stimson (but he has made a later comment questioning the accuracy of that alternative):

> Dissolve has a switch for 'Multipart' and 'Unsplit Lines'
>   http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005n000000 if you
>   select 'no multipart' and 'unsplit lines' it should leave the
>   unattached lines exactly as they are, only merging/dissolving lines
>   that share a common endpoint - no need to run multipart to single.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't give the question clearly. In the table, not all lines are adjacent. Therefore, I have to check whether lines are adjacent and only merge those adjacent lines.

Comment: Also, the Dissolve gives me another idea that is can I dissolve all the line first, and then split the dissolved line to separate lines if they are not touching.

Comment: Really neat method! Works for my case.

Comment: Dissolve has a switch for 'Multipart' and 'Unsplit Lines' http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005n000000 if you select 'no multipart' and 'unsplit lines' it *should* leave the unattached lines exactly as they are, only merging/dissolving lines that share a common endpoint - no need to run multipart to single.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I forgot about that but have now incorporated it into my answer.  Always feel free to add another answer or to edit mine when you see something like this.

Comment: I think it bears mentioning that sometimes the output doesn't work as expected if you set the parameters as suggested, either no dissolving occurs or the features are dissolved completely in rare instances. Perhaps this has improved since the last time I tried it; I would definitely suggest validating the results of the operation. To validate project to metres (or feet I suppose), feature vertices to points and then collect events - any event with a count greater than 1 is suspect and worth a second glance.